# Choose an activity to load in startup - Android

Tags: android, startup

I have an android application which needs to decide which activity to load first (from 2 activities) on startup. The application is a kind of an alarm. So, the thing is I have to launch one of those activities by checking whether there is already an alarm is set or no alarm is set.

1. Is there a way to check this on startup using AlarmManager class without conflicting with the default alarm application in my phone.
2. Or should I use a database of temporary data storing method to get the details.
3. How can I develop this.
   Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Define an activity that takes care of this. Give it the intent filter so it is launched first

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```
2. In this activity, perform the logic that decides which activity should be opened.

For example, my app has a SplashActivity that checks if a user is logged in. If there's none, it starts LoginActivity, if there is, it goes to content activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (userLoggedIn()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ContentActivity.class));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will do. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a common base `Activity` and in its `onCreate` method you can write logic to choose from your `Activity`s, and start the chosen `Activity` from there. The base `Activity` need not load any UI (i.e. need not call `setContentView`) and it can call `finish()` just after launching the `Intent`.